# How to open text file and parse it

Tags: vb.net

I have the following question. On my form I write away my form with the value "76,50" as "07650". Now I want to open my file again in the listbox with the value 76,50 instead of 07650.

```
Public Class AddwhenOpen 

Public number As Integer
Public name As String
Public Birthday As Integer
Public perc As Decimal
Public comboboxvalue As String

Public Function ToStringForPrinter() As Decimal

Return comboboxvalue & nummer.ToString.PadLeft(5) & naam.PadLeft(5) & Geboortejaar.ToString.PadRight(5) & (perc / 100).ToInt64("00,00")

End Function
```

Code for CLASS

```
`Public Class ChangeFormatBackToDecimal

Public number As Integer
Public name As String
Public Bday As Integer
Public perc As Decimal
Public comboboxvalue As String

Public Function TostringForPrinter() As String
    Return comboboxvalue & number.ToString.PadLeft(5) & name.PadLeft(5) & Bday.ToString.PadRight(5) & Format(perc / 100, "#00,00")
End Function`
```

Code when opening the file...

```
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim lijn As String

    'Keuzelijst leegmaken.
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()


    With dlgOpenen
        .Filter = "textfiles (*.txt) | *.txt"
        .FileName = ""
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\My Documents"
        .Title = "Open"
    End With

    If dlgOpenen.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        FileOpen(1, dlgOpen.FileName, OpenMode.Input)
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            line = LineInput(1)
            lstOutput.Items.Add(line)
        Loop
        FileClose(1)
    End If
    Resetdefaultvalue()
```

Dim data As New ChangeFormatBackToDecimal

```
    data.comboboxvalue = cboAfdeling.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(5) & cboKlasGetal.SelectedItem.ToString & cboAfdeling.SelectedItem.ToString & cboKlasLetter.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(5)

    data.number = CInt(txtNumber.Text)
    data.name = txtName.Text
    data.Bday = CInt(txtBday.Text)
    data.perc = CDec(txtPerc.Text)


    lstOutput.Items.Add(data)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Comment: using winforms or webforms?

Comment: Why are you saving the value as `07650`? Why not save it as `76.50` instead?

Comment: Using winforms. I have a class (thnx to really good help). I tried to reform the class that I have.
`Public Class AddwhenOpen
    Public number As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public Birthday As Integer
    Public perc As Decimal
    Public comboboxvalue As String


    Public Function ToStringForPrinter() As Decimal
        Return comboboxvalue & nummer.ToString.PadLeft(5) & naam.PadLeft(5) & Geboortejaar.ToString.PadRight(5) & (perc / 100).ToInt64("00,00")
    End Function`
But this didn't work :)...

Comment: When someone asks what have you tried so far, it means please post your code :-) ... So please post your code and put the code in the ACTUAL question not in comments :)

Comment: I have to save it as 07650 because that's the assignment :).
Then when I open the file... I want the value of "07650" to reform again to "76,50"... If you need more code... Watch How to save listbox to a textfile"...

Comment: So "07650" should parse out as the value 7650, in which case you can simply divide by 100 to get 76,50. What is the question here? Also note that if you have an *assignment*, perhaps you should talk to your fellow classmates about this?

Comment: Can't get reach of the classmates ... therefore my post here... Yes first I parse it, then divide by 100... But my code doesn't work... What am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change string 76,50 instead of 07650.

```
Dim n as Integer = val("07650")

Dim s as String = format(s/100)
```

This is optional ...

```
s = s.Replace(".",",") 
s = s.PadRight(5,"0")
```

ABOUT YOUR CODE :

It should be

```
Return comboboxvalue & nummer.ToString.PadLeft(5) & naam.PadLeft(5) & Geboortejaar.ToString.PadRight(5) & format(perc / 100,"#0.00")
```

Comment: "To change string" doesn't work... My value is in a variable wich is declared in an extra class... How do I get that value wich is saved as, for example "07650", in to the form again with the value of "76,50"...

Comment: My value "07650" is a string type. The only thing is... I can't get it wright :S

Comment: Thnx but it doesn't work :S. I think I'm doing something wrong,... again... I've put my code for the class and to open the file to the listbox in the topic above.

Comment: I've got an invalidCastException... at data.nummer = CInt(txtNummer.Text)

Comment: if not your txtnumber.text is not valid numeric text .. or try with convert.toint32(txtnumber.text) ..